# Facebook Workplace Opengraph - retrieve users wall view

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-wall, facebook-workplace

We want to integrate a users wall into our intranet as a first point of call. It'd be ideal if we could retrieve the view of the wall the user would see when they first log in but I can't seem to find an opengraph call to do this.

We could read the users feed and all the groups they have access to and then merge the posts together by date order. However, this isn't necessarily the way you see them when you access Facebook as it's affected by user interactions.

Does anybody have any idea if this is even remotely possible?

Comment: You can not get a users newsfeed. You can only get the posts that they have made.

Comment: This is looking like the only answer.